# Chrome extension to change chrome settings

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to create an extension to set certain settings on chrome such as popups etc.

I asked for `contentSettings` permission in my manifesto :

```
 "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*","contentSettings"
  ],
```

and I have the following js code to change the settings

```
var url = 'http://google.com';

var pattern = /^file:/.test(url) ? url : url.replace(/\/[^\/]*?$/, '/*');
var setting = 'popups';
console.log(' setting for '+pattern+': '+setting);

chrome.contentSettings[setting].set({
        'primaryPattern': pattern,
        'setting': 'allow'
      });
```

and I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'popups' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it your url permissions?  http://google.com isn't a pattern of http://*/*

Comment: Are you doing this from a background page, pop up or content script?

Comment: @Brian No I have the right URL permissions, I am running the script as "content_scripts" and I have console.log when the script is loaded. Thats where I get the error.

Comment: @rsanchez Its "content_scripts", the js is being ran but I get that error.

Answer (score 2):

Most chrome.* APIs are not available to content scripts. They can only be used from background or event pages, popups, or other extension views you define. If you need to initiate your action in response to something that depends on the contents of a page, you can send a message from your content script to a background or event page to carry it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks OK but you’ve spelled the setting wrong! It should be “pop-ups” not “popups”.

These strings are predefined constants so you gotta stick to what the Chrome API has declared.

Comment: Are you sure? I believe Chrome API says it's `chrome.contentSettings.popups`, or `chrome.contentSettings["popups"]`. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings

Comment: Both spellings are used in different urls so, no I'm no longer sure... https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: It is consistent: the use "pop-ups" in regular English text, but the property itself is named 'popups'.

Comment: That's where my confusion came... programing urls vs user urls. I'll delete this post if I can.

Comment: Can't delete it... ah well, onwards and upwards! :)

Comment: Why not? You ought to be able to delete your answers.The "delete" link at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Btw, it would be nice if we could enable/disable Java in this way but alas…